# Get all the data from amazon cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've created a schema

```js
type S3Object {
  bucket: String!
  region: String!
  key: String!
}

type Content @model @auth(rules: [{allow: owner}])
@searchable {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  subtitle: String
  description: String!
  url: String
  image: S3Object!
}
```

Also, I've created a form to add data to the server. This works for every authenticated user that I've tried.

Now, I would like to list all the content created for all user in the main page after a user login on the website. how can I do that?
I'm working with javascript and react and amazon cognito for authentication

```js
  async componentDidMount(){
    const contents = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listContents))
    console.log(contents);
  }
```

This snipped get the list of content create for the specific login user not for all.